# Return custom field based on other not requested field?

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

Let's say that I want to get a person's `age` using this query:

```
{
  getUser(id: "09d14db4-be1a-49d4-a0bd-6b46cc1ceabb") {
    full_name
    age
  }
}
```

I resolve my `getUser` query like this (I use `node.js`, `type-graphql` and `knex`):

```
async getUser(getUserArgs: GetUserArgs, fields: UserFields[]): Promise<User> {
  // Return ONLY ASKED FIELDS
  const response = await knex.select(this.getKnexFields(fields)).from(USER).whereRaw('id = ?', [getUserArgs.id]);
  // returns { full_name: 'John Smith' }
  return response[0];
}
```

The problem is that then I can't calculate `age` field, because I did not get `born_at` (datetime field stored in a db) in the first place:

```
@FieldResolver()
age(@Root() user: User, @Info() info: GraphQLResolveInfo): number {
  console.log(user); // { full_name: 'John Smith' }  no born_at field - no age, so error
  // calculate age from born_at
  return DateTime.fromJSDate(user.born_at).diff(DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date()), ['years']).years;
}
```

Is there some *fancy graphql-build-in* way / convention to predict that **born_at** will be needed instead of doing it manually through **info / context**?

Comment: there is no magic here ... you're asking for `age` but sth should ask for you about `born_at`? good joke .... *'Return ONLY ASKED FIELDS'* (`fields`) probably contains `age`, map it into `born_at`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always return full entity data from the query-level resolvers, so they are available for field resolvers.

The other solution is to manually maintain a list of required fields for field resolvers, so your "fields to knex" layer can always include them additionally".

Further improvements might be to can a list of additional columns based on the requested fields (thus the field resolvers that will be triggered).